# Chiral symmetry vs quantized Zak phase

Tags: topology, topological-insulators, topological-phase

I've been doing some condensed matter research about the topological phases in one dimension system and have some questions.

I've heard that the chiral symmetry leads to the $\pi$-quantization of Zak phase(1D integral of Berry phase), but actually I can not find any rigorous proof of it, many article just say chiral symmetry leads to $\pi$-quantized Zak phase. Can anyone gives me some hint or notes that rigorously prove this ?

Also, I have question on the topological number defined by "$\pi$-quantized Zak phase" and "1D winding number" , is this two same ? I mean, I know $\pi$-quantized Zak phase can only defined $Z_2$ classification since Zak phase can always have $2n\pi$ ambiguity due to gauge choice. But how about "1D winding number" ? It seems that "1D winding number" host $Z$ classification. So are they different ? Since many article just say Zak phase is winding number, I've been confused.

In this article : https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7242 the author says in the third paragraph in page 2 that

*In the case of non-interacting fermions, the topology of the
band structure is determined by its Zak phase [21] (or winding
number). While for a general 1D band structure this phase
may take arbitrary values, it is integer (i.e. Z) quantized (in
units of π) [37] when chiral symmetry is present, and Z2 quantized
for the SSH case.*

It sound weird since in my opinion Zak phase can only defined $Z_2$ classification because of $2n\pi$ ambiguity.

To sum up, my main question is what topological classification will Zak phase host. And does Zak phase same as winding number ?

I will be very grateful for any suggestion, thanks !